# Sort in a custom way with jquery .sort()

Tags: jquery

I have a list of fruits.

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Pineapple"];
```

I would like to sort them with jQuery `.sort()` by giving a set of values which should be put first:

```
var showFirst = ["Banana", "Apple", "Orange"]
```

The rest of the fruits should be added at the end in any particular order.

Can I use `fruits.sort()` for this and make it look something like this?

```
    fruits.sort(function (a, b) {
        var customOrder = ["Banana", "Apple", "Orange"]
        {
            return ?;
        };
    });
```

The outcome should be:
`fruits = ["Banana", "Apple", "Orange" "Mango", "Pineapple"];`

Comment: What if in the new list, one of `"Banana", "Apple", "Orange"` is not there? What should be the outcome?

Comment: If the only "sort order" you need is the three items you mention, why consider using "sort"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sort, you can simply compare to indexOf `a` versus `b`, but you'd have to check for -1 separately. By reversing the showfirst array, you can use sort directly:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Pineapple"];

var showFirst = ["Banana", "Apple", "Orange"];
var sorter = showFirst.reverse();
fruits.sort(function (a, b) {
        return sorter.indexOf(b) -  sorter.indexOf(a);
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mqj0sr0j/)

Comment: This almost does what I need! The only thing is that when I have multiple "Banana" values in the array, I would like them all to show at the beginning of the array.

Comment: Sorting this way, that should already happen. Did a quick test and seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/mqj0sr0j/1/ Unless I'm misunderstanding the intention?

Comment: You are right. It does put all the showFirst values at the beginning. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you say, any order after the first three, then you can do this way:

```
function sort(arr) {
  // Always show these first.
  var showFirst = ["Banana", "Apple", "Orange"];
  // Create a return variable.
  var finalArray = [];
  // Loop through the showFirst to add the array elements if present.
  $.each(showFirst, function (i, v) {
    if ($.inArray(v, arr)) {
      // Push this to the final in the same order.
      finalArray.push(v);
      // Remove it from the original array.
      arr[i] = undefined;
    }
  });
  // After this add the rest.
  $.each(arr, function (i, v) {
    if (typeof v != "undefined")
      finalArray.push(v);
  });
  // Return the final array.
  return finalArray;
}
```

So the above code is fully documented.